# Overwriting a file with export[SystemDialogInput[]]

Tags: export, dialog-window

When I use the following code:

`Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "myP1P3bmp.png"],Image[myBitMap, "Bit"], "PNG"];`

I get a somewhat unexpected behavior. I can perfectly save files with a name that does not exist in the directory I am saving in yet, but I cannot overwrite an already existing file. Mathematica seems to enter a never ending loop or the like. According to the documentation, I should be able to overwrite an existing file, shouldn't I?

Comment: `Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "myP1P3bmp.png"], 
 RandomImage[1, {10, 10}], "PNG"]` works fine on Win10 V10.3

Comment: Thanks. Your code indeed gives indeed a pop-up, as expected. After fiddling around, I found that the "are you sure" pop-up is actually popping behind! Behind the notebook, which you cannot minimize during execution. Weird.

Comment: My was on top. What OS are you using?

Comment: Win7 and mathematica 10.3. The only work around I can come up with is using the task manager to minimize the mathematica windows. This leaves the pop-up.Not very ellegant :)